# Dynamics365 Operations: Created/Updated timestamps with Data Entities

Tags: odata, axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I am new to Dynamics FnO, and recently followed the articles to access data through **oData**, and was successful.

What I see missing in the data objects that I normally receive in integrations out of the Microsoft World is the **created/updated timestamps**.

I am trying to put a synchronous data flow from FnO to my NodeJs application, so that my app keeps polling data from FnO whenever there is a change. This can be achieved easily if there were timestamps with the data that flows in.

Is there a way to setup those timestamps somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure that the underlying table that you are querying has the fields added on it, and also that the data entity you are accessing through odata has the fields setup up on it as well.

Make sure this is setup on the table:

[image]

And then you have to drag and drop the field(s) from the datasource field list to the exposed field list in the data entity:

[image]

After this, you will have these fields

Comment: Can I run all this in mac OS or Linux?

Comment: You will need to make modifications to the Dynamics AX app. Either the endpoint is providing the timestamp fields or it isn't. If it isn't, you need to change the server side code (make changes to AX using x++). For that, you will need a Windows based D365FO development environment.

Comment: Your answer may be perfect, but I can't confirm it because I have no knowledge of X++ nor do I have a Windows based D365FO development environment.

Comment: @rjv Guys where can I get this x++ environment to be able to do it? Is there a good tutorial about it?